# I cannot get strpos to work with newline

Tags: php, newline, strpos

I am very new to php and cannot find out how to fix this. I have a form and want to pass some string to it and have it checked with another file. It is working fine if all the strings are on the same line but as soon as I put in multiple lines of string, it will fail.

I have a php file with the following code:

```
<?php
echo "<center><form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
echo "<b></b><textarea name='texttofind' cols='80' rows='10'></textarea><br>";
echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' style='width:80px' value='Run' />";
echo "</form></center>";

$texttofind = $_POST['texttofind'];
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $texttofind = stripslashes($texttofind);
}
$texttofind = html_entity_decode($texttofind);
$s = file_get_contents ("/home/xxxxx/public_html/abc.txt");
if (strpos ($s, $texttofind) === false) {
    echo "not found";
}
else
    echo "found";
?>
```

and in abc.txt, I have

```
dog  
cat  
rat
```

Whenever, I open the php page and type in just dog or cat, it will be fine and show `'found'` message but when I type multiple lines like 'dog`<enter on keyboard>`cat' and click submit button, it will return with the `'not found'` message.

What is wrong with the code or anyway to adapt it so that it will be able to search multiple lines?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: so if you submit two words in 2 lines then you want to check for both? a simple loop will do here

Comment: your file may be using (say) `\n` as the line separators, but your browser is sending `\r\n`.

Comment: got the working code from Hanky. The problem is solved. Thanks Hanky, Dan and Marc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
$values=explode("\n",$txttofind);
foreach($values as $value)
{
    if (strpos ($s, $value) === false)
    {
        echo "$value : not found <br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "$value : found <br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That is only if you want to search for each input line individually

Comment: I need to search exactly the same as what I type, not each one individually. Thanks anyway Hanky.

Comment: Thats easy. Then run your own code but before you make the comparison run $s= str_replace("\r","",$s);  and also $texttofind=str_replace("\r","",$texttofind);

Comment: Your solution is great. That fixes my problem. I own you a keg of beer. Thanks Hanky.

Comment: @user1951663 glad to hear that. Anytime :)

Comment: @user1951663 maybe an Accept will do if not beer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you place your search words on new lines you are adding characters that do not exist in your comparison file.  Eg when you enter...

dog
cat
rat

You are actually sending a string that looks like...

"dog\ncat\nrat"

Where \n means character 13 or the standard non windows new line character.  The fix for this depends on what you want to do.  You can search for results using PHP's explode function to convert the input string into an array and then get positions for each word...

```
$inputs = explode("\n", $_POST['field']);
$positions = array();

foreach($inputs as $val)
    $positions[] = str_pos($compareTo, $val);
```

Now $positions should be an array of the str_pos's that where found for each line.

If you are still trying to search that the comparison file has all of the text you just don't care if it is on a new line or not you can simply strip out the new line characters all together (also remove \r just to be safe)

```
$inputs = str_replace("\n", "", $_POST['field']);
$inputs = str_replace("\r", "", $inputs);
```

Now inputs would be "dogcatrat".  You can use the second argument of str_replace to set a space instead of a \n to get back to the space separated list.

```
$inputs = str_replace("\n", " ", $_POST['field']);
$inputs = str_replace("\r", "", $inputs);
```

Yes we are still ignoring \r all together (silly windows).  All the same I suggest reading up on how to use array's, explode & implode and str_replace.  Many will comment on this and tell you that str_replace is bad and that you should learn regex.  As an experienced developer I find very few cases where regex replacements provide any better functionality in simple character replacement and it will cause you to learn a completely new language of commands.  For now ignore those who tell you to use regex but definitely learn regex in the near future.  You will need it eventually, just not for something of this nature.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: No problem, you can find contact details on my profile and my website if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at PHP_EOL . this is what you need to search in string.